# Excel VBA file name changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have to 2 Excel workbooks to work with: Book1october & Book2. Book1october18 is an import file, meaning that it changes monthly, along with the name (next month it will be Book1november18). I have to copy some data from Book1october to Book2 automatically through VBA code.

This is the code that I've written:

```
Windows("Book1october18").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("B2:AQ5").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("R2:BG5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

My problem is that I don't know how to write the code in order to make the actions that I want whenever the month's name changes and also the year. (I have to make it for all the months and 2019)

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: You could also have a dialog box asking the user to select the file they want to work on. (`Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`)

Answer (score 4):

You can automatically update your workbook name using the `Date()` function and `Format()`

```
Dim sWbName As String
sWbName = "Book1" & LCase(Format(Date, "mmmmyy"))

Debug.Print sWbName
'Prints Book1october18
```

Answer (score 3):

The name/path of the workbook doesn't need to matter. Use [K.Davis's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53047306/1188513) to come up with a filename, or prompt the user for a path/file to open - get that string into some `sourceBookPath` variable, then have the macro open the workbook. Now you can hold a reference to that `Workbook` object:

```
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Set sourceBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sourceBookPath)
```

Now, the worksheet.

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
```

If the sheet is always going to be named "Sheet1", then you can do this:

```
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Or, if the sheet is always going to be the first sheet in the book (regardless of its name), you can do this:

```
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets(1)
```

Once you have a `Worksheet` object, you can get the `Range` you need - but first you need your *target*. Again if "book2" is opened by the macro, things are much simpler:

```
Dim targetBook As Workbook
Set targetBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(targetBookPath)
```

Or is it *created* by the macro?

```
Set targetBook = Application.Workbooks.Add
```

Anyway, we want the first sheet:

```
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetBook.Worksheets(1)
```

And now we can copy from the source, and paste to the target:

```
sourceSheet.Range("B2:AQ5").Copy targetSheet.Range("R2:BG5")
```

And not once did we ever need to `.Select` or `.Activate` anything, and we never needed to care for any `Window`.

Comment: Nice visual on the avoidance of `.Select`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Windows("Book1october18").Activate
```

with:

```
s = LCase(Format(Now, "mmmm")) & Right(Year(Now), 2)
Windows(s).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

This is a recognition of the next month's document, assuming you have opened two documents.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(Wb.Name, "Book1") Then
            Set Wb1 = Wb
        ElseIf InStr(Wb.Name, "Book2") Then
            Set wb2 = Wb
        End If
    Next Wb

    Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:AQ5").Copy wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("r2")
End Sub
```